# replace words that starts with "(uuid: )"

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace text using javascript/regex

"TV "my-samsung" (UUID: a1c3bbc1d27c5be8:8baabe2fa7f5d9ca) is already switched off."

with

TV 'my-samsung' is already switched off.

by removing text (UUID: ) and replace " with '

Looks like regex can be used

```
  \([\s\S]*?\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xXDncn/1

or have also tried using replace method in JS

```
   str = str.replace("(UUID", "");
```

Comment: `s.replace(/\(UUID: .*?\) /, '').replace(/"/g,"'")`

Comment: Thanks Cherry. The UUID text is more precise, and that works much better!
If the string starts with " or ends with ", is there a way to use regex too?
I am not familiar with regex, but the other way could think of is using:
if s.startsWith(") s = s.substring(1);
if (s.endsWith(") s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1)

Comment: `s.replace(/^"|"$/g, '')`

Comment: Thank you! That works!
Let me see if can combine both regex into one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const str = '" "Tv "my-samsung" (UUID: a1c3bbc1d27c5be8:8baabe2fa7f5d9ca) is already switched-off""';
console.log(
   str.replace(/\s*\(UUID:[^()]*\)/g, '').replace(/^[\s"]+|[\s"]+$/g, '').replaceAll('"', "'")
)
```

See the first [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHQbvc/1). It matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(UUID:` - `(UUID:` string
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

The `g` flag makes it replace all occurrences.

The second regex removes trailing and leading whitespace and double quotation marks:

- `^[\s"]+` - one or more whitespaces and double quotes at the start of string
- `|` - or
- `[\s"]+$`  - one or more whitespaces and double quotes at the end of string.

The `.replaceAll('"', "'")` is necessary to replace all `"` with `'` chars.

It is not a good idea to merge these two operations into one as the replacements are different. Here is how it *could* be done, just for learning purposes:

```js
const str = '" "Tv "my-samsung" (UUID: a1c3bbc1d27c5be8:8baabe2fa7f5d9ca) is already switched-off""';
console.log(
   str.replace(/^[\s"]+|[\s"]+$|\s*\(UUID:[^()]*\)|(")/g, (x,y) => y ? "'" : "")
)
```

That is, `"` is captured into Group 1, the replacement is now a callable, where `x` is the whole match and `y` is the Group 1 contents. If Group 1 matched, the replacement is `'`, else, the replacement is an empty string (to remove the match found).

Comment: Thank you! 
if the string starts or ends with multiple quotation :
`" "Tv "my-samsung" (UUID: a1c3bbc1d27c5be8:8baabe2fa7f5d9ca) is already switched-off""`
Would like it to remove the multiple starting or ending multiple quotation and return `Tv 'my-samsung' is already switched-off"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, able to use backticks to format code

Comment: @user21 Ok, got it, you need to remove leading and trailing whitespaces and double quotation marks.

Comment: yes. I could only think of using substring method as is more familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks @wiktor that works like a charm. I'd need to read more on regex!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
str.replace(/\(.*?\)/, "")
str.replace(/\(.*?\)/, "with")
```

--- update ---

```
const str = `"TV "my-samsung" (UUID: a1c3bbc1d27c5be8:8baabe2fa7f5d9ca) is already switched off."`;
const a = str.replace(/"(.*?)\(.*\)(.*)"/, (a, b, c) => {
    return b.replace(/"/g, "'") + c
});
console.log(a); //TV 'my-samsung' is already switched off.
```

Comment: You can choose between the two methods.
The replacement of "with" is just an example.

I don't think I've checked the information on the rest of the values except for uuid. I'm learning a lot from your good answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I edited it rather than deleted it. I hope it's okay.

Comment: yun, what I said in the beginning is still not resolved: the string inside parentheses must start with `UUID:`. More, what if there are several such strings inside the text? Besides, what if there is no trailing `"`? Your regex won't work then. If the string does not start with `"`, it will not be handled correctly because the first `"` in your regex is not anchored. Also, have a look at the OP comments below my answer: there may be several double quotes and whitespaces at the start and end of the string and they need to be removed, too.

Comment: Congratulations. The questioner commented on your answer and you made a great answer based on it. :)

Comment: yun, it is not in the comments, see the question: *removing text `(UUID: )` and replace `"` with `'`*. See also the title of the question.

Comment: I will study English and regular expressions more and try to give you a good answer like you :)